# React Native components not rendering inside map() iterator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a method below to iterate through an object and render components. The method below works as expected.

```
  renderListOfMeals() {
    if (this.props.mealPlan !== undefined) {
      return (
        Object.values(this.props.mealPlan).map(meal =>
          <Meal key={meal.id} meal={meal} />
      )
    );
    }
}
```

I wanted to update the method to return a slightly different version of the Meal component based on if it had added to favorites or not. The method below returns the correct components but they do not render on the screen and I cannot figure out why.

```
  renderListOfMeals() {
    const { mealList, favourited } = this.props;

    if (mealList !== undefined) {
        Object.values(mealList).map(meal => {
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(favourited, meal.id)) {
            return <Meal key={meal.id} meal={meal} favourited />;
          }
            return <Meal key={meal.id} meal={meal} favourited={false} />;
        });
      }
    }
```

Below are the full classes for reference:

**ListOfMeals.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Meal from './Meal';

class ListOfMeals extends Component {
  /* Props
  * mealList: List of meal objects to be rendered
  * favourited: List of meals that are already favourited
  */


  renderListOfMeals() {
    const { mealList, favourited } = this.props;

    if (mealList !== undefined) {
        Object.values(mealList).map(meal => {
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(favourited, meal.id)) {
            return <Meal key={meal.id} meal={meal} favourited />;
          }
            return <Meal key={meal.id} meal={meal} favourited={false} />;
        });
      }
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.renderListOfMeals()}
      </View>
    );
  }

}

export default ListOfMeals;
```

**Meal.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import axios from 'axios';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import Config from '../../Config';
import { Card, CardSection, LoadingOverlay } from '../common';
import FoodRow from './FoodRow';
import { ActionButton } from './ActionButton';

class Meal extends Component {
  // Redux not needed here as no major state, only booleans used to alter rendering.. //
  state = { liked: false, favourited: false, loading: false };

    componentWillMount() {
      if (this.props.favourited) {
        this.setState({ favourited: true });
      }
    }

    getSimiliarMeals() {
      const mealId = this.props.meal.id;
      this.setState({ loading: true });
        axios.get(`${Config.BASE_URL}/meal/${mealId}/similar`)
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({ loading: false });
          Actions.ListOfMeals({ mealList: response.data });
        })
        .catch(this.setState({ loading: true }));
    }

    likeMeal() {
        const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
        const mealId = this.props.meal.id;
        this.setState({ loading: true });
          axios.post(`${Config.BASE_URL}/meal/${mealId}/like`, currentUser.uid)
          .then(response => {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
            this.setState({ liked: response.data });
          })
          .catch(this.setState({ loading: false }));
      }

    favOrUnfavMeal() {
      const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
      const meal = this.props.meal;
      this.setState({ loading: true });

      if (this.state.favourited) {
        firebase.database().ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/favouritedMeals/${meal.id}`)
        .set(null)
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({ loading: false });
          this.setState({ favourited: false });
      })
      .catch(this.setState({ loading: false }));
    } else {
      firebase.database().ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/favouritedMeals/${meal.id}`)
      .set(meal)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        this.setState({ favourited: true });
      })
      .catch(this.setState({ loading: false }));
    }
  }

    renderFoodRows() {
      return (
        Object.values(this.props.meal.mealFoods).map(food =>
          <FoodRow key={food.id} food={food} />
      )
    );
  }

  renderLike() {
    if (!this.state.liked) return <Icon name='thumb-up-outline' size={20} color='green' />;
  }

  renderFavouriteOrUnfavourite() {
    if (this.state.favourited) return <Icon name='heart' size={20} color='red' />;
      return <Icon name='heart-outline' size={20} />;
  }

  renderSimilarityRating() {
    const { tanimoto } = this.props.meal;
    if (tanimoto !== 0 && tanimoto !== undefined) {
      return (
        <CardSection>
          <Text style={styles.similarityText}>
            {Math.round(Number(tanimoto) * 100)}% also liked
          </Text>
        </CardSection>
      );
    }
  }

  renderLoading() {
    if (this.state.loading) return <LoadingOverlay />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <Card>

      <CardSection>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.nameHeader}>{this.props.meal.name}</Text>
        </View>
          <ActionButton onPress={this.likeMeal.bind(this)}>
            {this.renderLike()}
          </ActionButton>
          <ActionButton onPress={this.favOrUnfavMeal.bind(this)}>
            {this.renderFavouriteOrUnfavourite()}
          </ActionButton>
          <ActionButton onPress={this.getSimiliarMeals.bind(this)}>
            <Icon name='find-replace' size={20} color='orange' />
          </ActionButton>
      </CardSection>

        {this.renderSimilarityRating()}
        {this.renderFoodRows()}

        <CardSection>
          <Text style={styles.caloriesHeader}>
            {Math.round(this.props.meal.protein)}g protein
             / {Math.round(this.props.meal.carbs)}g carb
             / {Math.round(this.props.meal.fats)}g fat
          </Text>
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          <Text style={styles.caloriesHeader}>
            {Math.round(this.props.meal.calories)} calories
          </Text>
        </CardSection>

      </Card>
      {this.renderLoading()}
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = {
  nameHeader: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  caloriesHeader: {
    fontSize: 13,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  similarityText: {
    fontSize: 14.5,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'green',
    fontStyle: 'italic'
  }
};

export default Meal;
```

**EDIT:
The Correct Code**

```
  renderListOfMeals() {
    const { mealList, favouritedList } = this.props;

    if (mealList !== undefined) {
      return (
        Object.values(mealList).map(meal => {
          if (favouritedList !== undefined && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(favouritedList, meal.id)) {
            return <Meal key={meal.id} meal={meal} favourited favouritedList={favouritedList} />;
          }
            return <Meal key={meal.id} meal={meal} favourited={false} favouritedList={favouritedList} />;
        })
      );
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think it may have something to do with adding a bind(this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original version of the `renderListOfMeals` method, you have

```
return (
    Object.values(this.props.mealPlan).map(meal =>
      <Meal key={meal.id} meal={meal} />
  )
```

Whereas in your updated method, you're missing the `return` keyword before `Object.values(mealList).map(meal => { ... })` statement.

Comment: This is correct thank you. I will accept and paste in the code solution in a few minutes when able. Thank you very much.